# DNS Server (stand alone) serving AD domain. how to migrate to AD integrated DNS

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns

I have an AD domain with 2 sites the DNS role was configured on stand alone servers (each in 1 site) serving the AD domain as primary zone. I had added the new domain controller and integrated the DNS with AD (only on new domain controller. the integrated DNS shows the zone as AD integrated while on Stand alone DNS it is configured as primary. how can I merged the two zones and get rid of the stand alone DNS

Answer (score 1):

The AD DNS zones can't be AD integrated on non-domain joined DNS servers.

You'll need to install additional Domain Controllers or promote the standalone servers to Domain Controllers (joining them to the domain if needed) in order for the zone to be AD replicated to those other DNS servers.

Comment: Its a domain joined DNS Server but not the AD integrated. all the AD details (forest, domain, sites, msdcs) are sitting on the stand alone as primary zone. when I added the a new domain controller with dns service installed and pointed to stand alone DNS. it pull up some information from it but not the complete structure

Comment: A zone can't be AD integrated if it isn't on a Domain Controller. Promote the standalone DNS servers to Domain Controllers.

Comment: Thank you, this is what exactly found and understand from Microsoft article